# Can you iterate dynamically through struct fields in Go via the json key field?

Tags: go

```
type Params struct {            
  MyNum    string `json:"req_num"`
}
```

So I need to assign the value of `MyNum` to another variable given a "`req_num`" string key for some functionality I'm writing in the `beego` framework.  Is this possible in `Go` and if so how?

I looked at the reflect library and couldn't find a way.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do. params is a variable of type Params with the value of MyNum initialized to *"123"* let's say.  f currently does not get *"123"*. It says **""** when I log it to the console.

```
b := "req_num"
r := reflect.ValueOf(params)
f := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName(b)
```

EDIT: I will be doing this for multiple params (above I set b to an example field value "req_num") and I want to write it so I don't have to know the name of the field stored in b.

Comment: Please create an example of what you want to do. You can lookup fields and tags via reflection, since this is how the json package works.

Comment: Hi @JimB - example of what I'm trying to do added...

Comment: `req_num` is [struct tag](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag), `FieldByName` need field name(`MyNum`). you can first loop over the struct, build `tag -> field name` map, then can get value by tag

Answer (score 2):

Use the JSON codec to do the work:

```
p, _ := json.Marshal(Params{MyNum: "123"}) // encode to JSON
var m map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal(p, &m)                      // decode to map
fmt.Println(m["req_num"])                  // get value from the map
```

[Runnable example in the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qrPzRCFhWeU)

You can avoid allocating the entire JSON document in memory by [piping](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe) an [encoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder) to a [decoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder):

```
value := Params{MyNum: "123"}
r, w := io.Pipe()
go func() {
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(value)
    w.Close()
}()
var m map[string]interface{}
json.NewDecoder(r).Decode(&m)
fmt.Println(m["req_num"])
```

[Runnable example in the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/85KRVAbwSWg)

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the fields in the type looking for a field with given JSON tag name. The value is in the corresponding field of the value.

```
name := "req_num"
v := reflect.ValueOf(Params{MyNum: "Hello"})
t := v.Type()
for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
    if strings.Split(t.Field(i).Tag.Get("json"), ",")[0] == name {
        fmt.Printf("the value is %q\n", v.Field(i).Interface().(string))
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/_8sI_oCitml